# My onboarding experience "of"/"with"/"using" the Telegram app

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'm a user experience researcher and I need to write about my own onboarding experience using the Telegram application.

I don't know which sentence sounds better.

1. My onboarding experience with Telegram.
2. My onboarding experience of Telegram.
3. My onboarding experience using Telegram?
4. Something else?

Comment: I would probably say “with,” but “using” sounds fine to me too. “Of” sounds wrong to me. (I’m American.)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Davislor As a  British English speaker I find "experience of" better than "experience with". In fact I would insert "of" before "using" in option 3. For me "experience with" is only appropriate when describing a shared experience, for instance "I enjoyed the trip to Snowdonia, I shared the experience with Jane who speaks Welsh quite well."

Comment: As a second thought are you referring to the use of Telegram to introduce you as an employer to a new new company or are you using "onboarding" to mean "learning and starting to use Telegram"? If it's the latter then I wouldn't use "onboarding" at all as "onboarding" has a very specific meaning as an HR term and, unless you have joined the company responsible for Telegram as an employee, "onboarding" does not have the meaning you seem to be intending.

Comment: @BoldBen That’s different from how I’d use prepositions, but good to keep in mind. I’d normally say “My experience of Telegram” if I meant all my experiences of using Telegram.

Comment: "onboarding with Telegram" sounds to me like Telegram is the company you're joining, not the app being used while joining another company.

Comment: @Barmar Glad to see that you have a similar reaction to the apparent use of 'onboarding' in the question. To me it's rather nasty buzz speak anyway (a bit like the  verb to 'to leverage') but to allow its meaning to creep in the way that the OP seems to be doing makes it even worse.

Comment: @BoldBen Like it or not, it's common business terminology now. I remember a year or two trying to find a dictionary that had the now common meaning of "monetize". Even online dictionaries have a hard time keeping up with the pace of language change.

Comment: @Barmar I think it's the 'mission creep' in these buzz words that puts me off them. When "to leverage" first started to appear with its current positive meaning of "making the most of your investment" 30-40 years ago what annoyed me was that it was a financial sector technical term with negative connotations (a company or corporation with a high level of borrowing compared to its value has been described as "highly leveraged" for years) and suddenly marketing people were using the term as a positive: "onbording" seems to be being used sloppily in the current question.